# What is difference between socket connection and TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, ip-address, layer4

We know TCP socket is port numbers and IP addresses. Is TCP socket connection is 3-way handshake:the SYN packet, the SYN-ACK packet, and the ACK packet?

Is TCP socket connection follows TCP stack?

And is TCP connection  follows the TCP stack for data transmission?

My question is how TCP stack, TCP connection and TCP socket connection are interrelated? And how could we differentiate them? And socket connection uses IP address at later that is responsible by OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP connection is identified by a pair of sockets (local and remote). Connecting to a remote TCP and handshaking gives you a bidirectional connection. It is like a pair of pipes (one in each direction) between the hosts, and anything going in one end of a pipe comes out the other end.

*[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html)* explains (see highlights, but the RFC goes into much more detail):

> Multiplexing:
>
> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
> communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
> addresses or ports within each host.  Concatenated with the network
> and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
> socket. A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection. That
> is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections.
>
> The binding of ports to processes is handled independently by each
> Host. However, it proves useful to attach frequently used processes
> (e.g., a "logger" or timesharing service) to fixed sockets which are
> made known to the public. These services can then be accessed through
> the known addresses. Establishing and learning the port addresses of
> other processes may involve more dynamic mechanisms.
>
> Connections:
>
> The reliability and flow control mechanisms described above require
> that TCPs initialize and maintain certain status information for each
> data stream. ***The combination of this information, including
> sockets, sequence numbers, and window sizes, is called a
> connection.*** Each connection is uniquely specified by a pair of
> sockets identifying its two sides.
>
> When two processes wish to communicate, their TCP's must first
> establish a connection (initialize the status information on each
> side). When their communication is complete, the connection is
> terminated or closed to free the resources for other uses.
>
> Since connections must be established between unreliable hosts and
> over the unreliable internet communication system, a handshake
> mechanism with clock-based sequence numbers is used to avoid erroneous
> initialization of connections.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135471/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-what-is-difference-between-socket-connection).

Comment: TCP is doing connection by 3 way handshake, so it needs to do socket at the end?

Comment: The three-way handshake uses the sockets, and it creates a connection (or fails) in the end. A socket is created when an application requests it of TCP.

Comment: When SYN segment(during connection establishment 3-way handshake) is sent then at receiver sides socket is created?

Comment: I mean after sender creating socket it will sent SYN segment(during connection establishment 3-way handshake) then receiver will create it's socket at its side? Am I correct?

Comment: No, the sockets exist before the connection. A connection requires sockets in order for the connection to be created. Again, it is explained in the RFC. It explains passive and active Opens for sockets. A application must create a socket to send a SYN, and if the socket to which it is trying to connect on the remote host does not already exist, the remote TCP will refuse the connection request.

Comment: That's I comments above. But in receiver side also has exists socket  before syn has reached?

Comment: "_If the socket to which it is trying to connect on the remote host does not already exist, the remote TCP will refuse the connection request._" Sockets must already exist on both sides before a connection can be created.

Comment: But one thing confusing me socket created by TCP or application?

Comment: The socket is created when an application asks TCP to create one, either with a specific port number, or with Port 0 that tells TCP to give it an ephemeral port. Again, this is all detailed in the RFC.

Comment: on same port 80 could listen more than one request at the same time? For example if one user generate two http request simultaneously, then server listen both request at the same on same port 80? Am I correct?

Comment: Your comment was answered [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45843/why-does-tcp-need-more-than-just-one-port#comment142642_45844).